# How can I show mi async Task<object> return into my View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm pretty new with ASP.Net Core and I'm trying to show my async Task Filter return into my View but not sure how to...

This is my Controller code:

```
public class OrderNumberController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string orderNumber)
        {
            string[] locales = HPMSConstants.System.SupportedLocales.OrderBy(l => l).ToArray();
            ViewBag.Locales = locales;
          

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<PaymentGatewayTransactionManagerService.PaymentGatewayRecord> Filter(string orderNumber)
        {
            var result = await GetOrders(orderNumber);
            
            return result;
        }

        private async Task<PaymentGatewayTransactionManagerService.PaymentGatewayRecord> GetOrders(string orderNumber)
        {
            var httpBinding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            // var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://pgtms.local.myherbalife.com/PaymentGatewayTransactionManager/Service.svc");
            //var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://zus2q1ssb000000.hrbl.net:8330/Service.svc");
            var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://zuswqa4svc01:8330/Service.svc");
            PaymentGatewayTransactionManagerClient clientService = new PaymentGatewayTransactionManagerClient(httpBinding, address);

            var result = await clientService.GetPaymentGatewayRecordAsync(orderNumber);

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: why does it have to be involved with 3 methods? Do you really think they are all needed for us to guess out what the exact issue you have?

Comment: I guess that depends on how you *want* to show this information in your view.  If the user is already on a page and you want them to be able to fetch this data while still on that page then it sounds like you would make an AJAX request to this controller action.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I see what you are asking. In the second two methods you are returning a `Task<something>` where the "something" is the result that you got after awaiting the result from an async method call. The first method is showing an MVC view controller method returning a view. It turns out that method is coded wrong. It should be (ignoring the first two lines which seem unrelated to the problem)

```
public IActionResult Index(string orderNumber)
{
    string[] locales = HPMSConstants.System.SupportedLocales.OrderBy(l => l).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Locales = locales;
  

    return View();
}
```

This you don't need the `async Task<IActionResult>` because you are not awaiting any asynchronous methods within the method shown. `View()` is a method on the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` which is not asynchronous and returns a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult`, which extends a ActionResult.

So the short answer is, just make sure your method returns the values it says it does in the method signature and make sure not to ignore the warnings and errors in Visual Studio or Visual Code. There is a warning if you add `async` to a method but you do not `await` anything in the body. There is an error if you try to return a `Task<IActionResult>` but are returing something that implements `IActionResult` instead.